# How to select exact string from List?

Tags: c#, json, list, linq

I have Json List

```
    {
        country: "INDIA      "
        },
 {
        country: "INDIA      "
        },
        {
        country: "INDIANA    "
        },
        {
    country: "AFRICA      "
        }
```

I am filtering country from the List which I have

```
var flights = new List<allflights>();
flights = flights.Where(x => x.Country.Contains(selectedvalue)).ToList();
```

In the above case if I select INDIA, INDIANA is also added to the List. But I want to pick only exact country which I am selecting. Need all the INDIA items to be added to the list. Don't want any other items to be added.

Comment: `contains` cannot be used in your scenario.  try `==`

Comment: That's a strange country list. It only contains one country: India. Neither Indiana or Africa are countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to trim strings before comparing and use == instead of contains

```
var selectedvalue="INDIA";

List<allflights> selectedFlights = allFlights
.Where(a=> a.Country.Trim() == selectedvalue.Trim())
.ToList();
```

I can't see your data, so maybe  you will need to use

```
a.Country.Trim().ToLower() == selectedvalue.Trim().ToLower())
```

Comment: Hey, depending on the current culture, ToLowerInvarriant() can be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your linq expression like below

```
flights.Where(x => x.Country.Equals(selectedvalue)).ToList();
```

Note: You can add additional code to trim the strings to fine tune per your needs

Comment: sorry, this didn't work.